# How can use order by column with out using top in sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've this query and it's getting error "`The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`"

I've solved this issue with using `TOP` in the inner query, but some cases I wouldn't measure the record count. Is there any other possibility to sort it out ?

```
select *
from rs_column_lang
where column_id in (
    select column_id
    from rs_column
    order by column_id
)
```

Comment: it's not a view, which is base table only

Comment: . . It is very important to understand that ordering in a subquery has no (official) effect on the order of the outside query, with or without `top`.  The only `order by` guaranteed to affect the results is one in the outer query.  Always.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff. But after provided top which was order properly, i took that desired result set.

Comment: . . The `top` will operate on the "sorted" data to get the correct result.  That does not mean that the data in the outer query will be returned in sorted order.

Comment: That's because it doesn't make *sense*. "Is A in (A,B,C)?" and "Is A in (B,C,A)?" are exactly the same question - the order of the elements doesn't affect it one jot. You're not allowed it because it tends to imply that there's some mis-thinking going on somewhere.

Comment: because i think it works both inner table and outer table has the column_id in the same sequence.

Comment: Nice explanation. my understaning improved somewhat better. Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Essentially the only effect you would get by putting an order by in that particular subselect is slowing the overall query down. In fact the only time an order by in a subselect would have a positive effect is if you include a TOP to get specific rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an `order by` in your inner query doesn't make sense. You're checking your outer query for matching records, but you're reading the entire table on your inner query to find the matches. Sorting that inner query serves no purpose, so SQL Server yells at you for it.

Like the other answers indicate, assuming your goal is to sort the results, your `order by` should be part of your outer query, not the inner one.

The reason a `top` would work in the inner query is that it would change the results of the query, depending on what you're ordering by. But just changing the order would not change the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select  * from rs_column_lang
where column_id in 
(
select column_id from rs_column
)
order by column_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  * from rs_column_lang
where column_id in (
select column_id from rs_column
)
order by column_id
```

Comment: if i do this like, it's order the value for outer query. My requirement is the inner query should be sorted

Comment: could you please add some table examples of initial data and desired results?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah Sorting your inner query has **no effect** on the correctness of the query as a whole. You're just asking if items are in a set of `{ 1, 2, 3, 4}` which is the same as asking if they are in the set of `{4, 1, 3, 2}`.

Answer (score 0):

column_id contains the same data in rs_column_lang and rs_column so you can simply move your ORDER BY in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM rs_column_lang
WHERE column_id IN (
    SELECT column_id FROM rs_column
)
ORDER BY column_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **optimize your query** like this

```
select A.*
from rs_column_lang A
  inner join rs_column B on A.column_id = B.column_id
order by A.column_id
```

because this is simple inner join
you will get significant performance improvement if DB optimizer not recognized inner join

Comment: Should this be an order by B.column_id as he was originally attempting to order by the subquery (in your example that has been replaced by a joined table aliased as B.)

Comment: There is no difference because A.column_id = B.column_id